# Iframe Canvas application with Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, master-pages

I am developing an Iframe-Canvas Application.

I am using Master Page to gain permission access & display few details, that works good.

Then on content Page I want to display a textbox & linkbutton so user can post status on their wall & here I get error

**(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

here's my code :

Site.master.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me","user_birthday","user_location","offline_access","publish_stream" } };

    if (auth.Authorize())
    {
        ShowFacebookContent();
    }
}
private void ShowFacebookContent()
{
    var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("me");
    lblName.Text = myInfo.name;
    imgProfile.ImageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + myInfo.id + "/picture";
    lblBirthday.Text = (myInfo.birthday == null ? string.Empty : DateTime.Parse(myInfo.birthday).ToString("dd-MMM-yy"));
    lblHometown.Text = (myInfo.hometown.name == null ? string.Empty : myInfo.hometown.name);
    lblLocation.Text = (myInfo.location.name == null ? string.Empty : myInfo.location.name);
    pnlHello.Visible = true;
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
    //var fb = new FacebookWebClient();

    dynamic feedparameters = new ExpandoObject();
    feedparameters.message = (message_txt.Text == null ? " " : message_txt.Text);
    feedparameters.user_message_prompt = "userPrompt";

    dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", feedparameters);
}
```

I am pretty new to FacebookSDK so any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wel finally found what was the problem. Needed to add a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<%: Request.Params["signed_request"]%>"/>
```

I think this is neither mentioned any where in the documentation nor in the Provided Samples.

Comment: ta - this has helped out a massive amount

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to pass in "access_token" as a string value.  You need to get your hands on the actual access_token value provided to you by Facebook when a user session is established, and then pass in that access_token value into the constructor.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171309/facebook-c-sdk-and-access-token) for more info.